# what is FractionalTranslation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation

I am learning flutter for some time. But I do not seem to understand fully what is FractionalTranslation class despite docs and some examples.

Documentation says: `FractionalTranslation` class applies a translation transformation before painting its child.

But what does it mean? Could you explain it to me in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

FractionalTranslation class is essentially a type of Transform, and it is also used to do The difference of translation transformation is that **its translation unit is a multiple of the width and height of the control**. It is defined as follows

```
FractionalTranslation({
Key key, 
@required Offset translation, 
bool transformHitTests: true, 
Widget child })
```

It can be seen that its definition is the Transform.translatesame. The difference is translation the understanding of parameters. Let’s use a few examples to explain the use of FractionalTranslation

FractionalTranslation use
The translation distance of the Text control to the right is 0.5 times the width of the Text control

```
Container(
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: FractionalTranslation(
        translation: Offset(0.5, 0),
        child: Text("Hello world")),
      ),
```

The distance to translate the Text control to the right is 2 times the width of the Text control

```
Container(
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: FractionalTranslation(
        translation: Offset(2, 0),
        child: Text("Hello world")),
      ),
```

Move the Text control to the right and down. The right translation distance is 1 times the Text width, and the downward translation distance is 1.5 times the Text height.

```
Container(
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: FractionalTranslation(
        translation: Offset(1, 1.5),
        child: Text("Hello world")),
      ),
```

Complete example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class TransformDemo extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
      home: HomeWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State createState() {
    return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<HomeWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("TransformDemo"),),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: FractionalTranslation(
            translation: Offset(1, 0),
        child: Text("Hello world")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]